# Misunderstanding of the null object pattern

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the null object pattern to implement a linked list, and it's starting to get out of control. While using just plain `null`, I could check if a node was null, then decide what to call on it. With the null object pattern, any operation I need to do on a node must be defined for each type (in this case, a concrete node, and a concrete null node). When it was only 2 operations, that was fine, but I'm finding that I'm adding on as I go, and it's starting to get messy:

```
package tutorial

trait AbNode[+A] {
    def getNext[B >: A]: AbNode[B]
    def hasNext: Boolean
    def replaceTail[B >: A](newNext:AbNode[B]): AbNode[B]
    def foreach[B >: A, C](f: B => C): AbNode[C]
    def findLast[B >: A]: AbNode[B]
}

case class Node[+A](cargo:A,next:AbNode[A] = NullNode) extends AbNode[A] {
    override def getNext[B >: A]: AbNode[B] = next

    override def hasNext: Boolean = next != NullNode

    override def replaceTail[B >: A](newTail:AbNode[B]): AbNode[B] =
        this.copy(next = newTail)

    override def foreach[B >: A, C](f: B => C): AbNode[C] = 
        Node( f(cargo) , next.foreach(f) )

    override def findLast[B >: A]: AbNode[B] = next.findLast
}

case object NullNode extends AbNode[Nothing] {
    override def getNext[B >: Nothing]: AbNode[Nothing] = NullNode

    override def hasNext: Boolean = false

    override def replaceTail[B >: Nothing](newCargo:AbNode[B]): AbNode[Nothing] = NullNode

    override def foreach[B >: Nothing, C](f: B => C): AbNode[Nothing] = NullNode

    override def findLast[B >: Nothing]: AbNode[Nothing] = NullNode
}

//map _ [] = []
//map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs  


class LinkedList[A] {
    var head: AbNode[A] = NullNode
    var last: AbNode[A] = head
    var size: Int = 0

    def this(head:AbNode[A], last:AbNode[A]) = {
        this
        this.head = head
        this.last = last
    }

    def length: Int = size
    def maxIndex: Int = size - 1

    def pushFront(cargo:A) = {
        val oldHead = head
        head = Node(cargo).replaceTail(oldHead)
        size += 1
    }

    def pushBack(cargo:A) = {
        last.replaceTail(Node(cargo))
        last = last.getNext
        size += 1
    }

    def foreach[B](f: A => B): LinkedList[B] = {
        val newHead = head.foreach(f)
        new LinkedList(newHead, newHead.findLast)
    }

    def get(index:Int): A = {
        var curNode = head
        for (i <- 0 to maxIndex) {
            curNode = curNode.getNext
        }
        curNode.cargo // <- Whoops. Now I need to declare getCargo in the AbNode trait, in case curNode is a NullNode
    }
}
```

Am I using it incorrectly? It seems ridiculous to need to keep adding things to a trait.

Comment: Hint: you have to *somehow* handle the situation where `curNode` ends up being either a sentinel node (without value) or a node with value. Whether via pattern matching, common interface member that throws an exception in the `Empty` node or maybe even something else - that's up to you.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question is, is the situation above normal, or am I implementing something incorrectly?

Comment: To a certain extent this is normal. You're hitting the so-called "expression problem"; some approaches make it easy to add types, other approaches make it easy to add functions. If you just want to write good Scala, specific methods might be better implemented as pattern matches rather than abstract methods - this should let you write code similar to when you were null-checking. Otherwise, try putting more of the implementations in `AbNode`. Arguably some of your operations should behave more consistently - e.g. `replaceTail` on an empty list could probably make a new one.

Comment: @lmm Thanks. To make them based on pattern matching, I would have to make the methods "static" wouldn't I? Or is there a way of doing it without a companion object? And yes, the replaceTail in NullNode is broken. I was getting a weird error last night and gave up. I had forgotten about it, so it's a good thing you mentioned it, or that would have broke other methods.

Comment: You can do `this match {...}` in `AbNode`, the standard library does it sometimes, though IMO that's a confusing style.

Comment: @lmm I created a companion object for Node, and defined a replaceTail that uses a match, and it works as intended. It requires a bit more writing to use though, as I need to pass in the node I want to change with the new tail, and I have to prefix it with "Node.". I'll try other way you mentioned and see how it turns out. Thanks.

Comment: @lmm And using the `this match... ` way would arguably be less safe, because it will only catch a missed case at runtime, instead of compile time, correct?

Comment: Instead of getNext hasNext methods, a `def next: Option[Node]` would be *much* more idiomatic scala

Comment: @Daenyth Thanks. That would bloat the code would't it, as it would require wrapping/unwrapping? I'll try it and see how it looks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate When you use maps/for comprehensions/pattern matching properly it comes to much less code. Using `null` in scala is a terrible anti-pattern.

Comment: @Daenyth I wasn't comparing using `null` and using `Option`; I already know using `null` will bloat code. I was comparing using `Option` and using the 2 methods.

Comment: `if (ll.hasNext) doStuff(ll.getNext)` vs `ll.next.map(doStuff)` - if ll is mutable using hasNext/getNext has multithreaded race condition issues because the state could change between calls

Comment: Fair point, thank you.

Comment: If you make the trait sealed it should warn if you miss a case.

Comment: @lmm Cool, thank you. Sealing a trait essentially makes it final outside of the file right? Nothing outside of the source file can extend it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's what sealed does, yes. As a result, the compiler will refuse to compile incomplete pattern matches on that parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking all the comments, this is what I have. Either:

- Define the currently abstract methods in AbNode to use pattern matching:

  ```
  trait AbNode[+A] {
      def replaceTail[B >: A](newTail:AbNode[B]): AbNode[B] = this match {
          case Node(c,n)  => Node(c,newTail)
          case NullNode   => newTail
      }
  }
  ```
- Use a companion object object, and take them out of the abstract class:

  ```
  object Node {
      def replaceTail[A](node:AbNode[A], newTail:AbNode[A]): AbNode[A] = node match {
          case Node(x,n)  => Node(x,newTail)
          case NullNode   => newTail
      }
  }
  ```

Either way, pattern matching seems to be the less painful solution. The problem with this approach is, if I need to add a new type of node, I'll need to update every method (I think this is the trade off that `@lmm` mentioned). I can see myself adding more methods then types, so I'll stick with this.

The other downside is, as far as I understand, this won't create a compile-time error if I neglect a case. In my original way, it will fail at compile time because I didn't fulfill the trait. Here, it will compile, but can fail with a matching-error if I forget a case.

Thanks guys